# IK Making Foot, Toe and Shin Bone rotate as it animates

Tags: rigging

I've been trying to rig this character and for some reason as I'm animating the foot controller, the foot and toe bone decide to rotate and do a 180. The pole target for the knees are moving with the controller and the ik target for the foot is following the entire foot controller. The knee IK seems to be fine, but the foot and toe just instantly want to flip.

If anybody can help that be great!
https://www.dropbox.com/s/57u8et6koybhb7g/IK_Problem.gif?dl=0

EDIT: Hah, I'm an idiot, the pole targets for the toe and foot weren't following the main foot controller, No need for this question anymore.